# Rails 3: On a local server (# rails server), my images weren't found, although the correct location is given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I started the rails server with `rails server`.

My images are in public/images, i.e. the image public/images/rails.png is put into html with `<img src="/images/rails.png" />` just as the `image_tag` helper generates it.

But by any reason, the picture isn't found. If I enter the source of the file directly into the browser, I get a routing error: "No route matches http://0.0.0.0:3000/images/rails.png".

Any help?

Yours,

Joern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your environments' config file, ie. `config/environments/production.rb`. If there's a setting `config.serve_static_assets = false` , the problem you described will occur.